# If $G$ is non-abelian, then $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is not a normal subgroup of the group of all bijective mappings $G \to G$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and let $\mathfrak{S}(G)$ be the set of all bijective mappings from $G$ to $G$.

Show that: If $G$ is non-abelian, then $\operatorname{Inn}(G):=\{\kappa_a  \mid a\in G\}$ is not a normal subgroup of $(\mathfrak{S}(G),\circ)$

First of all, this is not homework, but we had it in university as an exercise and didn't get a solution from our lecturer.
So I am just looking for a correct proof, since we have easter holidays and it is not possible to ask him.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $G$ is not abelian, there exists $g \in G \setminus Z(G)$, and hence there exists $h \in G$ with $h^{-1}gh \ne g$. So the inner automorphism $\kappa_h$ does not fix $g$. Let $x$ be the transposition $(1,g) \in {\rm Sym}(G)$. Then $(1,g)^{-1}\kappa_h(1,g)$ does not fix $1$ and so cannot be lie in ${\rm Aut}(G)$.

Comment: sorry but what means: "cannot be lie in $Aut(G)$" ?

Comment: @PaulH I think the answer uses the following subgroups: ${\rm Inn}(G)\subseteq{\rm Aut}(G)\subseteq{\rm Sym}(G)$ Here ${\rm Sym}(G)$ is the same thing your question calls $\mathfrak{S}(G)$, i.e. the group of _all_ bijective mappings $G\to G$ with composition. __Sym__ for "symmetric group". And ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is the subset whose members respect the groups structure, i.e. they are groups homomorphism, and because they are bijective are isomorphisms. __Aut__ for "automorphism group", because an automorphism means an isomorphism from something to itself. _(continued)_

Comment: _(continued)_ And finally ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is the subset thereof where each member is a conjugation $\kappa_g$ by some element $g$ in $G$. __Inn__ for "inner automorphism group".

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is finite,

Let $G$ be a group of order $n$ sice $G$ is nonabelian $6\leq n$.

$Inn(G)\cong G/Z(G)$ so $|Inn(G)|\leq n < n!/2$

Since $S_n$ has uniqe normal subgroup of order $n!/2$, $Inn(G)$ is not normal in $S_G$. (notice that $S_n\cong S_G$).

Comment: Who said that $G$ was finite?

Comment: Oh, I missed this point.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{Inn}(G)\unlhd$ $\mathfrak{S}(G)$ if and only if, for all $a\in G$ and $\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}(G)$, there is $b\in G$ such that $\sigma^{-1}\kappa_a\sigma=\kappa_b$, where $\kappa_x$ is the conjugation by the element $x$. In turn, $\sigma^{-1}\kappa_a\sigma=\kappa_b$ if and only if (definition), for every $g\in G$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\sigma^{-1}(\kappa_a(\sigma(g)))=\kappa_b(g)
&&\iff \\
&\sigma^{-1}(a^{-1}\sigma(g)a)=b^{-1}gb &&\iff \\
&a^{-1}\sigma(g)a=\sigma(b^{-1}gb) &&\color\red{\stackrel{g=1}{\Longrightarrow}} \\
&\sigma(1)a=a\sigma(1) &&\Longrightarrow \\
&G\text{ is abelian} \\
\end{alignat}
where the last implication holds because $\{\sigma(1),\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}(G)\}=G$. The claim follows by taking the contrapositive.