# A Group G is abelian $\Leftrightarrow$ $ Inn(G)$ is a normal subgroup of Sym(G)

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

First of all I don´t think that this question is answered here

[If $G$ is non-abelian, then $Inn(G)$ is not a normal subgroup of the group of all bijective mappings $G \to G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750877/if-g-is-non-abelian-then-inng-is-not-a-normal-subgroup-of-the-group-of-al)

because in my opinion this is only one direction of the proof. I would be very thankfull if somebody can do me a favor and answers my question. The question is:

Let (G, *) be a group. Let $\mathcal S(G)=\{f:G\to G\space|f\space is\space bijective\}$ be the symmetric group and $Inn(G)=\{\kappa_{a}\space|\space a\in G\}$ the inner automorphisms. Now I want to show:

> G is abelian $\Leftrightarrow$ Inn(G) is a normal subgroup of $\mathcal S(G)$

Comment: The linked question proves the nontrivial direction. If $G$ is abelian, what is $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$?

Comment: Please don't just reask the question if you disagree with the duplicate mark.

Comment: What's the site policy here - should this be flagged for removal as an inconsiderate attempt to go around the marking of the other question as a duplicate? This behavior should be discouraged.